# Where should I put the Broadcom BCM4313 driver for Asus 1018?

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I have a driver file `wl.ko`. How can I install it or where should I put it that my wifi works on my Asus 1018?

Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g LP-PHY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only load the kernel module if it was compiled for it. You can check that by running `modinfo -F vermagic /path/to/wl.ko`. It's output would look like:

```
2.6.35-28-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

The `2.6.35-28-generic` part is the kernel version for which the module was compiled. It should match the output of `uname -r`. If these versions do match, proceed. Otherwise, **stop**.

Before following the next steps, test whether the module would load:

```
modprobe -nv wl
```

If the module would load, it shows something like:

```
insmod /lib/modules/2.6.35-28-generic/kernel/net/wireless/wl.ko
```

1. Copy the module to the modules directory by running:

   ```
   sudo install -m 644 /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/wireless/wl.ko
   ```
2. Update the module dependencies map for all modules by running:

   ```
   sudo depmod -a
   ```
3. Load the kernel module in the current session:

   ```
   sudo modprobe wl
   ```

   If you get any errors, do not proceed, remove the module by running:

   ```
   sudo rm /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/wireless/wl.ko
   sudo depmod -a
   ```
4. Add `wl` to `/etc/modules` by running:

   ```
   echo wl | tee -a /etc/modules
   ```
5. Update your initial ramdisk with the kernel module by running:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

Comment: I write this comment on my asus per wifi :)

Answer (score 0):

It goes in  `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/kernel/net/wireless` where  is most likely 2.6.35-22-generic, to make sure of it do:

```
$ ls /lib/modules/
```

And see the highest entry there.

Make sure to make a `modprobe wl` after you got that file copied